# Mean of outlinks of a sparse matrix

Tags: matlab

So I'm working with sparse matrix and I have to find out different info about a very big one (10^6 size) and I need to find out the mean of the outlinks. Just to be sure I think mean is what you get from 3+4+5/3=4, 4 is the mean.

I thought of something like this:

```
 [row,col] = find(A(:,2),1,'first')
```

and then I would do 1/numberInThatIndex or something similar, since it's a S-matrix (pretty sure it's called that).

And I would iterate column by column but for some reason it's not giving me the first number in each column, if I do find(A(:,1),1,'first') it does give me the first in the first column, but not in the second if I change it to A(:,2).

I'd also need something to store that index to access the value, I thought of a 2xN vector but I guess it's not the best idea. I mean, find is going to give me index, but I need the value in that index, and then store that or show it. Not sure if I'm explaining myself properly but I'm trying, sorry about that.

Just to be clear both when I input A(:,1) and A(:,2) it gives me index from the first column, and I do not want that, I want first element found from each column, so I can calculate the mean out of the number in that index.

edit: allright it seems like that indeed does work, but when I was checking the results I was putting 3817 instead of 3871 that was the given answer and so I found a 0 when I wanted something that's not a zero. Not sure if I should delete all of this.

Comment: What do you mean by *outlink*? Do you want to calculate the means of each column?

Comment: I don't understand your question. In case you did not find the solution yourself try to explain what you are trying to implement using a small example and what output you expect.

Comment: Outlink is the... name given to the value of a certain index in the matrix. Since it's mostly full of 0's, if A(652,1) is not zero it means there are that number of pages being referenced by that "page" being a page each column. So if the column 1 has 5 outlinks, each of one have the value of 0.2, so that means it's pointing to 5 other pages. It's not the mean of each column, but the mean of... all of the columns I guess. But not the sum of each column, since that I know gives me a value of 1 (it has 5 values of 0.2, all summed gives a 1.0)

Comment: So the `i`th column has `n(i)` nonzero entries, each of which is `v(i) := 1/n(i)` and you want to compute the mean of all the `v(i)`? Or do you want to compute the mean of all `n(i)`?

Comment: I want to compute the mean of the sum of the v(i). But first I have to find said values, that's why I'm trying to use the find. As I put in the edit, I think the command is now correct, now I need to store all the values I get and add them to get the mean, which I'm failing to do for some reason (loop is probably coded wrong)

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem, you can do the following:

```
numberNonZerosPerColumn = sum(S~=0,1);
meanValue = nanmean(1./numberNonZerosPerColumn);
```

- Count the number of nonzero elements in every column `n(i)`
- Compute the values `v(i)` that are stored there, which are defined by `v(i) := 1/n(i)`
- Take the mean of those values where `n(i)` is not zero (i.e. summing all those values, where `v(i)` is not `NaN` and divide by the number of columns that contain at least one zero)

If you want to treat columns without any nonzero entry as `v(i):= 0`, but still use them in your mean, you can use:

```
numberNonZerosPerColumn = sum(S~=0,1);
meanValue = nansum(1./numberNonZerosPerColumn)/size(S,2);
```